# Radial Slide In effect like in Material Design

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve the radial appearance of the element on my page in  the same way it could be done in Material Design as a radial mask.

My HTML contains:

```
<div class="map"></div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.map {
 width:100%;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
 }
.l {
animation: fromLeft 1s;
z-index: 9;
transition: all 3s;
background: red;
}

@keyframes fromLeft {
from {
clip-path: circle(0 at bottom 0px left 0px);
background: transparent;
}
to {
clip-path: circle(280px at bottom 100px left 100px);
background:red !important;
}
}
```

The effect I am getting is just a fade in but not a radial one.

Can anybody please help me with what I am doing wrong?

My codepen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWXwAr

Please feel free to amend it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within my original css code especially for hiding the element from the beginning. Please use the example below if any one has the same issue.

```
shape-inside: circle(0px at 0px 0px);
-webkit-clip-path: circle(0px at 0px 0px);
```

or

```
shape-inside: circle(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-clip-path: circle(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWXwAr